# Problems with PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, pythonpath

From the command line (Mac OS), when I execute 'echo $PYTHONPATH' I get:

```
> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
```

If I then enter the Python interpreter and do the following:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['PYTHONPATH']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'PYTHONPATH'
```

Why would this happen?

Comment: Why would your PYTHONPATH be set to a location that Python searches anyway?

Comment: Remember the contents of $PYTHONPATH get appended to sys.path automatically, but they should also appear in os.environ (probably is as the first answer indicates).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to export it to the environment so that subprocesses can access it; it's currently only a bash variable.

```
export PYTHONPATH
```